# what is the exact usage of xmlns in xml, and html

Tags: html, xml, namespaces

Does any one know what is the exact usage of `xmlns` in HTML, XML files?

**Edit**: Why do we need this namespace? What is its usage?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation/28098405#28098405

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `xmlns` attribute declares an [XML Namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). The [Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) standard discusses this element in depth.

Namespaces are used primarily to avoid conflicts between element names when mixing XML languages. If you have a particular application that you have questions about, perhaps you could post an example.

Answer (score 19):

The `xmlns` attribute has special handling, that allows the declaration of a namespace.

All names, such as tag names, in a document belong to a namespace.  In the absence of the `xmlns` attribute all the names belong to the "no name" namespace.  Hence:-

```
<root><item /></root>
```

In the above example both `root` and `item` are names in the "no name" namespace. Whereas:-

```
<root xmlns="urn:mydomain.com:mystuff"><item /></root>
```

Now `root` and `item` exist in the "urn:mydomain.com:mystuff" namespace.

The `xmlns` can further define additional namespaces elements of which can be distinguished from others by using an alias prefix:-

```
<root xmlns="urn:mydomain.com:mystuff" xmlns:a="urn:otherdomain.com:other">
    <item>
       <a:supplement />
    </item> 
</root>
```

In this case `root` and `item` continue to be in the "urn:mydomain.com:mystuff" namespace but `a:supplement` indicates that the name `supplement` is in the "urn:otherdomain.com:other" namespace.

**What does this acheive?**

The X in XML stands for eXtensible.  One goal is to allow additional information to layer onto an existing document, i.e., the ability to extend the document. Consider:-

Party A create a document:-

```
 <root>
    <item />
 <root>
```

Party B extends the document by including additional information:-

```
 <root>
    <item />
    <supplement />
 </root>
```

Later Party A adds new info to their original form of the document and just so happen to also use the name `supplement` in their original.  We could end up with something like:-

```
 <root>
    <item />
    <supplement />
    <supplement />
 </root>
```

Which supplement element belongs to which party?  By using namespaces the document would look like this:-

```
 <root xmlns="urn:mydomain.com:mystuff" xmlns:a="urn:otherdomain.com:other">
    <item />
    <supplement />
    <a:supplement />
 </root>
```

Now when it comes to parsing and querying the XML its clear which element belongs to whom.  Namespaces elimnate the collision between what would otherwise be a global set of simple names.

Comment: When using the urn form is best practice to use a domain name you own since others are highly unlikely to use a domain name they don't own in their urn definitions.  In other cases you could use a URL.

Answer (score 2):

XML namespaces help contextualize elements an attributes, among other things. It also offers a precise identification for a particular element or attribute.

For instance, the `<html>` element can be defined by anyone and have any meaning. However, the `<html>` element within the *http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml* namespace is unique and refers to the XHTML.

Namespaces also prove useful when dealing with [homographs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph), when using multiple XML languages in a single file.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, xmlns is just a talisman to make moving from and to XHTML easier. It doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces let you reduce ambiguity when there are duplicates. You could have a `<title>` tag that refers to authors and `<title>` tag that refers to a salutation, like Mr., Mrs. etc. To differentiate, you could assign them to different namespaces.

You can also use namespaces when validating documents for conformance to a particular standard/restrictions, where the namespace would indicate to what "Schema" that the document is belonging to.