# What does xmlns="" exactly mean

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces

Given the following (piece of) a soap call;

```
<m1:NextCommencementDateInput xmlns:m1="http://foo.bar.com/Types">
    <aDate xmlns="">2010-06-02</aDate>
</m1:NextCommencementDateInput>
```

Apperantly this is the same as (when validating against the xsd using XMLSpy)

```
<m1:NextCommencementDateInput xmlns:m1="http://foo.bar.com/Types">
    <aDate>2010-06-02</aDate>
</m1:NextCommencementDateInput>
```

So what does xmlns="" do exactly ?

Edit: To elaborate why I'm asking this is because I'm calling a third party and they are now stating that we should remove xmlns="" from our requests. I however think they are the same and they should change their side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the exact usage of xmlns in xml, and html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372064/what-is-the-exact-usage-of-xmlns-in-xml-and-html)

Comment: (Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630468/what-is-xmlns-in-every-wpf-file)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.
Raymond ask about specific use of xmlns while the links you provided are talking about xmlns in general.

Comment: Indeed, I understand the usage of xmlns, however I'm puzzled with the empty namespace.

Answer (score 6):

`xmlns=""` clears definition of default namespace (aka empty prefix). After this declaration all elements without prefix are considered to have null namespace.

So the difference is:

- First example (with xmlns="") clears empty prefix so aDate element has null namespace.
- Second example doesn't clear it. Namespace of aDate element depends on namespace declaration in containing scope. If there is active xmlns="some:namespace" declaration, aDate will have this namespace. Otherwise it will have null namespace.

Additionally some XML parsers complain on xmlns="" if there is no active xmlns="some:namespace" declaration to clear...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [XML Namespace specification (§6.2)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting), they are completely identical other than for the extra attribute itself (which your implementation may or may not hide from you).

Comment: According to the spec that you link to they are *not* the same (but it would depend on the surrounding XML).

Comment: That would indeed depend on the context. I was taking the example as a whole document.