# Spring JPA & Hibernate persistence_1_0.xsd not found

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

So i Have this problem in implementing JPA and Hibernate in Spring WS. 
I have configured everything correctly and according to tutorial it should work - but it is not.

Problem lies in `persistance.xml`, here it is how it looks:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistance_1_0.xsd"
            version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the exception i am getting:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [persistence_1_0.xsd] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.PersistenceUnitReader.validateResource(PersistenceUnitReader.java:281)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.PersistenceUnitReader.readPersistenceUnitInfos(PersistenceUnitReader.java:108)
    ... 57 more
```

I am struggling with this since a while... Do anyone have an idea what am i missing?

Comment: It' s http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd (notice the 'e' instead of 'a' in 'persistence')

Comment: that eliminates the problem shown on screen, i will remove it, thank you @ccheneson, however problem with persistence_1_0.xsd not found remain the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include appropriate jar file containing the persistence_1_0.xsd.

This is explained here.

[what is the use of xsi:schemaLocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation)

Comment: is there any jar or maven dependency that include `persistence_1_0.xsd`? i can't find any..

Comment: It depends on the JPA used. For Hibernate its                 <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

Comment: Can you check if the jar file is in WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for attention, problem lied indeed in dependancy of  my project. Adding spring-jpa-2.0.8.jar solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

There was a type in the url to the .xsd file.  Try using: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd .  A good way to debug these types of issues is to try to hit the url in your browser, a successful request denotes a valid link.

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
                http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
            version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="hibernatePersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You make sure your project name does not contain any spaces, nor should the path to the project.  This creates an error in Hibernate entity manager.

Comment: I'll keep looking into it.  Just for kicks clean your project.  In Eclipse, Project > Clean All.  ALso where do you have your persistence.xml file within your project?

Comment: project is clean. `persistence.xml` according to war is in WEB-INF/classes/META-INF

Comment: try switching the auto ddl generation from none to validate or simply removing the property.  I do not believe none is a valid value, probally won't fix anything but worth a shot

Comment: Does your project name/paths contain any spaces? http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?26209-JPA-Persistence-xml-parse-error

Comment: i did switched to `value="created"` and no spaces in my name or paths