# Understanding Spring beans tag declaration

Tags: java, spring

I am new to Spring and trying to understand the beans tag that is declared in my spring configuration file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

I am trying to understand these 5 lines of my code. The first line says that it is an XML file. Cans someone please help me in understanding the other 4 lines, and the reason to provide that information to Spring application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't got anything to do with `Spring`. It's [XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) & [Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp) basics.

Basically all the tags that you'll use in the xml document have to be predefined somewhere. Similar to declaring your variables before using them. `xmlns` defines the **n**ame**s**pace (akin to packages) where these are stored. Then `schemaLocation` actually tells the file to refer for that namespace. For the full details regarding syntax, it's best to through the tutorials.

You also might want to go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17099848/2173960) as to why the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace doesn't have a schema file defined.

Answer (score 0):

The other lines only define some prefixes / namespaces that you then can use in your XML file. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).