# How to resolve namespace file location

Tags: java, tomcat, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

In one xslt I found namespace as `xmlns:ns="http://www.sometext.co.jp/ns"` but this url returns 404 error and there is no url mapping in tomcat container.
Could anyone please let me know how and where I found the namespace file and the function defined in it.

Comment: Namespaces don't have to point to actual pages.

Comment: You might want to read this: [what is the use of xsi:schemaLocation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation)

Answer (score 3):

[Namespace names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_names) only look like an URI (by convention) but they can be nearly any arbitrary name. An excerpt from the linked wiki page:

> A namespace name is a uniform resource identifier (URI). Typically, the URI chosen for the namespace of a given XML vocabulary describes a resource under the control of the author or organization defining the vocabulary, such as a URL for the author's Web server. However, the namespace specification does not require nor suggest that the namespace URI be used to retrieve information; it is simply treated by an XML parser as a string.

That simply means that you cannot expect to fetch anything from that URL.