# XSD: Namespace not working http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, xsd, wsdl2java

I want to create Java classes but failed below exception come,

> Error resolving component 'q1:ArrayOflong'. It was detected that
>   'q1:ArrayOflong' is in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays', but
>   components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema
>   document

what is alternative url for this
http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh632574(v=office.12).aspx ?

Comment: @Aaron how can i used in our xsd as namespace?

Comment: You could add schemaLocation pointing to the xsd file in files which require it. Otherwise `wsdl2java` might have a mechanism to reference additional schema files, but I didn't find it.

Comment: @Aaron can you give me detail, i am new in this side

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation) explains it well. You will want to provide a location for the `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation` namespace's declaration instead of relying on downloading it from the internet.

Comment: @Aaron thanks problem solved 
<xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" schemaLocation="serialization_arrays.xsd"/>

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm voting to close as duplicate of the linked question since it's what mainly helped you there I guess.